# Change mail-chimp campaign segment using mail-chimp API

Tags: mailchimp

I Have already created campaigns using mail-chimp API but i want to achive to update the segments so i can send that campaign to different user every next time

i know to update campaing there is update method in Campaigns.php but when i passing the argumrnts

```
$this->update('campaignID', 'segment_opts',['saved_segment_id'=>'']);
```

ti gives me error
**"match" must be "any" or "all"**
Please suggest something so i can apply

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If we want unset the segment for specific campaign then you should call

```
MailchimpWrapper::campaigns()->update($cid, $valueName, '');
```

So it will unset the segment and this campaign will send every member of campaigns list